# Appending to []interface{} problems

Tags: go

I am using two nested interface slices to provide record separation. I load a couple of dataItem into an interface slice (**var record []interface{}**)

Then I load that interface slice into another interface slice (**var db []interface{}**).

So I should have:  **db[0]record_org**

So then I clear the previous record slice (**var record []interface{}**)

Now here is the problem: I load the record slice with new dataItem.

Now without doing anything else the first dataItem in DB changes??

What am I missing about interfaces where a nested Interface can change its parents data???

I include a working example of the problem so the whole world can wonder at my stupidity.

**---------------------------- testDB.go --------------------------------**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

//
// Data Base Structures and Variables
//
var record []interface{}

var db []interface{}

func newWorkDataItem(exercise, date, side, notes, reps, weight string) (list map[string]string) {
    wdList := make(map[string]string)
    wdList["Exercise"] = exercise
    wdList["Data"] = date
    wdList["Side"] = side
    wdList["Notes"] = notes
    wdList["Reps"] = reps
    wdList["Weight"] = weight
    return wdList
}

//
// Main Function
//
func main() {
    //
    // Load Current Date
    //
    t := time.Now()
    d := fmt.Sprintf("%d %d %d", t.Month(), t.Day(), t.Year())
    //
    // Create Database Records
    //
    record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWC", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))
    record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWC", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))
    db = append(db, record)
    fmt.Println("Database1 = ", db)

    record = record[:0]
    fmt.Println("Record: ", record)
    record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWT", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))

    fmt.Println("Database2 = ", db)
}
```

**---------------------- Displayed Results --------------------------**

Database1 =  [[map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5]]]

Record:  []

Database2 =  [[map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5]]]

Answer (score 0):

A slice is made of three values. The pointer to the data buffer, the len and the capacity. When you assign a slice, you make a copy of the three values.

So when you append record to `db` the first time, it copies the pointer to data and the len. By changing the length of record, you don’t change the length of the copy in `db`.
This is why you still have the two values in the db.

You have to override `db[0]` with the truncated record so that `db` has the new record length.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

//
// Data Base Structures and Variables
//
var record []interface{}

var db []interface{}

func newWorkDataItem(exercise, date, side, notes, reps, weight string) (list map[string]string) {
    wdList := make(map[string]string)
    wdList["Exercise"] = exercise
    wdList["Data"] = date
    wdList["Side"] = side
    wdList["Notes"] = notes
    wdList["Reps"] = reps
    wdList["Weight"] = weight
    return wdList
}

//
// Main Function
//
func main() {
    //
    // Load Current Date
    //
    t := time.Now()
    d := fmt.Sprintf("%d %d %d", t.Month(), t.Day(), t.Year())
    //
    // Create Database Records
    //
    record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWC", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))
    record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWC", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))
    db = append(db, record)
    fmt.Println("Database1 = ", db)

    record = record[:0]
    fmt.Println("Record: ", record)
    record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWT", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))

    db[0] = record // <- override db[0] with new record slice

    fmt.Println("Database2 = ", db)

}
```

outputs the expected result

```
Database1 =  [[map[Data:11 10 2009 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 10 2009 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5]]]
Record:  []
Database2 =  [[map[Data:11 10 2009 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5]]]
```

See this [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8lHPudcVlo5) demonstration.

Comment: The answer you gave is good at explaining part of the problem.

Comment: What I am trying to do is put a collection of records as one entry into the db interface:   db [0] [record, record, record...], [1] [record, record, record...]      WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?   Posting a New example